# how to get an pinterest access token

Tags: java, pinterest

**i am using rest api to get an access toke of my user using following link**
`https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=my id&client_secret=my secret&code="+oauthVerifier+`

i am getting the response as

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 3, "host": "devplatform-devapi-prod-4a8937b3", "generated_at": "Tue, 28 Jun 2016 06:06:56 +0000", "message": "Authorization failed.", "data": null}
```

what shod i do to get my users access token

Comment: Did you follow the entire oAuth2 flow? The above step is the last one and from my perspective missing some parameters?

Comment: yes i have follow the entier oAuth2 flow if you know which parameters is missing please let me know

Comment: Sorry messed up auth code and access token For an access token this seems valid as from the syntax and params. Did you URL-encode the values properly?

Comment: yes i have tried that too still i am getting 401 as a response or let me know weather i need to get any approved mail conformation from pinterest to access my app@AxelAmthor