# Getting Error when try to get Pinterest Access Token

Tags: java, api, postman, access-token, pinterest

My question is similar [to this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070424/how-to-get-an-pinterest-access-token)
I have followed every step trying to get a Pinterest access token.
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/
I '
1. Created an app in the Pinterest developer dashboard
2. Got my authorization code without any problems
3. Tried to query my access token like in the docs:

```
POST https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=888888888888888&client_secret=9999999999999999999999&code=00000000000000
```

I tried to get it using curl command also.
Using Postman to get an access token is possible(Configure the OAuth flow:). 
But from java or postman i pull above endpoint then getting this error  {"error": "invalid_grant"}

Can anybody help me and tell me what could go wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!