# Getting 405 Error When Trying to Get Pinterest Access Token

Tags: api, pinterest

My question is similar to the one at [[Getting Error when try to get Pinterest Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276705/getting-error-when-try-to-get-pinterest-access-token][1])

I have followed every step trying to get a Pinterest access token. https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/ I ' 1. Created an app in the Pinterest developer dashboard 2. Got my authorization code without any problems 3. Tried to query my access token like in the docs:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=888888888888888&client_secret=9999999999999999999999&code=00000000000000
```

But I get the following response...

{
  "message": "405 Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL.", 
  "type": "http"
}

My app uses ALL https and nothing at all refers to http including the web site I'm using the pinterest app for.

I created a support ticket with my host provider and they have no clue. I create a support message with pinterest but so far they have no idea. Sent another response to them today hoping they know why I get 405 error response.

Let me know if you have gotten this error and what is a possible fix to get an access token.

Answer (score 1):

The method the error message is referring to is the HTTP Method, i.e. GET. Try sending the token request with a POST method.

Comment: Thanks, encountered the same issue. I was sending POST instead of GET